# Workflow running with error

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I'm getting the attached error message for my test workflow. I can't seem to find out what is causing it.[image]

Comment: can you share the workflow logic? Looks like you are referencing a column that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

First check that whether "New Employee Form" column exists in your list or not. After that terminate all the instances of your workflow and then start your workflow again.